# One key for one language

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

If you have only 2 languages on Windows to switch, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch between them.

But if the count of languages is more than 2 (I have 4), it becomes tricky to use the same key shortcut to switch them in round manner. Also, there is an option to assign separate shortcuts for each language (for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and etc.), but this solution is tricky too, because you have to use both hands to switch the language.

What I need is a way to assign **one key for one language**. My keyboard has a few keys which I don't use (those keys like 'Open browser', 'Open mail', 'Print' and etc.). How can I assign them for switching languages?

Comment: Those 'Open browser', 'Open mail', 'Print' keys are specific to the keyboard you're using (you probably have a separate keyboard driver). Isn't there a way to reprogram those to do Ctrl-Alt-1? Note that any solution in that direction would be for your keyboard type only. What make is it?

Comment: No, driver operates on a lower level, between the virtual keys and the keyboard device. So my solution will work on those keyboards, which support virtual keys like VK_LAUNCH_MAIL, VK_PRINT and etc. (complete list is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Basically I need to assign, for instance, virtual key VK_HELP to press Ctrl+Alt+1.

Comment: Take a look at [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).